# How to read syntheticClickType value in WKNavigationAction

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

```
import WebKit
let action = WKNavigationAction()
print("\(action.syntheticClickType)")
```

This ends up with error message:

```
error: value of type 'WKNavigationAction' has no member 'syntheticClickType'
action.syntheticClickType
```

Is it possible to somehow get the value of syntheticClickType ?

Comment: simply.


**navigationAction.value(forKeyPath: "syntheticClickType")**

it can get syntheticClickType value.

I wonder what value it is anyway.

Comment: It seems that when some UI interaction triggers a navigation (and also the coordinates of the position of the click are reported), the syntheticClickType is set to 1. However, when you programmatically load the content with webview.loadHTMLString() the navigationActionPolicy callback reports a syntheticClickType of 0, as well as the coordinates x/y of the ‘nonexisting’ click being  0/0

Comment: And when it is set to 0 print() reports ‘nil’ , whereas when it is set to 1 print() reports •syntheticClickType: Optional(<_WKUserInitiatedAction: 0x100ef4040; consumed = NO>)

Comment: @JayChoi • BTW: where is the documentation for navigationAction.value(forKeyPath:) - I couldn’t find anything in the navigationAction docs? It is a subclass of NSObject though, so is it a property of NSObject? I just found • <https://developer.limneos.net/index.php?ios=12.1&framework=WebKit.framework&header=WKNavigationAction.h> •  and with your method I can get all the values for the properties like e.g. ‘isRedirect’ - that helps a lot, as navigationAction.description doesn’t tell you this...

Comment: @mramosch I earned this knowledge from below document. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107i